# Any Logic Freezes after 36 replications

Tags: freeze, anylogic, montecarlo

I'm running a stochastic experiment and would therefore like to do N=500 (or some reasonably large N) replications of the simulation before collecting averaged results.

I've set up a Monte Carlo experiment to do this, and because I was told AnyLogic doesn't naturally average outputs over replications, I cumulatively add the output of each experiment and then once all experiments are finished I divide by the number of replications I ran. I don't store the outputs of each experiment just the cumulative value.

My problem is that the experiment seems to freeze after 36 replications and I'm not sure why this might happen. Note that Each replication takes around 5 seconds to run (and they are not taking progressively longer each time).

Has anyone else experienced something like this/can anyone suggest a way to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Is anything written to the console? Like " insufficient memory of for the java runtime"

Comment: Nothing prints out to screen no. I have seen those errors before so I know what you mean. I've tried to design the experiment so that only the collection that holds the results remains across all replications. At the start of each run I clear the agents and populate them again so I can't see why memory usage would increase as I do more replications.

Comment: One option for fault finding is to trace the replication, seed and day for every experiment... then you will soon see which experiment and seed is failing on which day... and then you try and run that exact seed in single run mode and see if you can replicate the failure

Comment: Thank you that's a good suggestion, I didn't know that the seed could be printed out - I'll look into that - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, had it many times. Two options:

1. too little memory: increase the experiment memory
2. It is a fault in your model, has nothing to do with AnyLogic :) . You need to do some investigations yourself, probably some special infinite loop triggered in that iteration.

Comment: I've done some more digging by putting some trace calls in the java actions I wrote to see where exactly it stops and the point at which the model freezes is in between replications. It completes all the java actions I ask it to within replication 36 and then won't start replication 37. I also printed the seed and ran the experiment that freezes individually and it runs fine as an individual simulation experiment. I'm not sure what else to try, but what I have noticed is the experiment pauses for quite some time between all replications - do you know what goes on in between replications?

Comment: you probably write a ton of data to some dbase or you do not have enough memory assigned to the experiment. Also, try running sequential, not in parallel

Comment: Thank you for the reply. To give more information, I empty the data base after each run because I keep a cumulative total of all the statistics I need (calculated from the database populated at the end of a run) in a collection object. These are divided by the total number of replications at the end of the simulation to give the averaged statistics I want. I increased the memory after your first comment but I don't know enough about Anylogic to be able to check what is enough - could you guide me here? I believe the experiment runs sequentially anyway.

Comment: Best always ask a new question ("how to see memory") here on SOF, it does not work like a forum :) See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow